# Why are promises written like "then(..).catch(..)"?

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I'm new to JavaScript. When we use.then and .catch, May I know why we write it like

```
const getIDs = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    resolve([523, 883, 432, 974]);
  }, 1500);
});
```

Why is it written like:

```
getIDs
.then(IDs => {
 console.log(IDs);
})
.catch(error => {
 console.log('Error!!');
});
```

Instead of something like:

```
getIDs.then(IDs => {
  console.log(IDs);
 });
// note: access getIDs again!
getIDs.catch(error => {
  console.log('Error!!');
});
```

What's the logic behind it? Thank you so much!

Comment: it's just the way it is. why is the grass green? why is the sky blue? :-D

Comment: @PaulFitzgerald Things "have colors" for reasons - the sky being blue is actually quite a complex topic. However, it's about asking an appropriate question..

Comment: Thank you so much! So both syntax are the same? I don't understand why in the first example we use .then and directly followed by .catch . The then and catch are both methods of the getIDs object, but why we call the two methods directly followed by each other like.then().catch()?

Comment: a lot of it comes from the history of javascript being call-back driven (which has its pros/cons)

Comment: @Ying look into promise chaining https://javascript.info/promise-chaining

Comment: Are you look for the concept of "method chaining"?

Comment: Note: it's [roughly] same difference with using: `then(..).then(..)` vs `x.then(..); x.then(..);`. And yes, they are different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `then` clause creates a new promise, so calling `catch` on this subsequent promise can catch different exceptions.

In the second snippet, you're catching exceptions from the initial `getIDs` promise only.

Answer (score 2):

Using this:

```
getIDs
.then(IDs => {
    console.log(IDs);
})
.catch(error => {
    console.log('Error!!');
});
```

you also catch errors of previous `then` functions while with:

```
getIDs.then(IDs => {
    console.log(IDs);
});
// note: access getIDs again!
getIDs.catch(error => {
    console.log('Error!!');
});
```

you only catch errors from `getIDs`.